# Speed optimization with -B; are __pycache__ still generated somewhere?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**NOTE that the question was updated based on comments, and the reason for the speed up was found during this work, as it often happens :-)**

For experiments to optimize Python 3.4 load time, with Python `-B` option for "don't write .py[co] files on import" to avoid local `__pycache__` files, I created this code, since I found that most time was spent in `import`s:

```
import datetime

modules = ['my_module_1', 'my_module_2']

time_sum = datetime.timedelta()  # Zero delta for start
for module in modules:
    time_begin = datetime.datetime.now()
    __import__(module)
    time_sum += datetime.datetime.now() - time_begin
print('{:.<10s}: {:.03f} s'.format('TOTAL', time_sum.total_seconds()))
```

With the `-B` option, I saw TOTAL runtimes for Win7 cmd (net drive), Win7 Cygwin (net drive), and CentOS 6.3 (local drive), for each platform at fresh copies, as:

1. 0.763 s, 0.652 s, 0.070 s
2. 0.655 s, 0.586 s, 0.069 s
3. 0.583 s, 0.596 s, 0.069 s

So it appears that even without local `__pycache__` files, there is some optimization done from first to subsequent runs, but this is probably due to buffering of files retrieved over the net drive, as @PeterSutton points out in a comment.

Without the `-B` option, then results were:

1. 0.853 s, 0.833 s, 0.073 s
2. 0.578 s, 0.590 s, 0.052 s
3. 0.567 s, 0.569 s, 0.052 s

So this clearly shows the speed improvement by local `__pycache__` files.

So does Python generate `__pycache__` files elsewhere (at some location temporary location) for source code at a specific location?  **No, but files are buffered in kernel.**

Comment: Is this the kernel caching the files or inodes in memory?

Comment: How are you running your benchmarks?

Comment: How does this performance compare to *not* passing `-B`?

Comment: You are measuring a single import, and this is not enough to have a clear, representative number. What you should do is e.g. call *__import__()* 1000 times (remembering to delete the module from *sys.modules* after importing it) and measure the total time taken by all the 1000 imports. Maybe take a look at [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html).